# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg, smartcontracts, web3js

In my NuxtJS project, I cannot call my smart contract function inside a for loop. whenever I try to call outside of for loop it works well. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let listOf = this.contract
const contractAddress = await this.cont.methods.contracts(2).call({
  from: this.ethAddress
})
console.log("contract address in 2 index " + contractAddress) // it worrks
await this.contract.methods.getContractcount().call({
    from: this.ethAddress
  },
  function (error, result) {
    if (!error) {

      var log = result
      console.log(log)
      var ContractList = async (log) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < log; i++) {
          console.log("==== " + i)


          await listOf.methods.contracts(i).call({
              from: this.ethAddress
            })
            .then(function (result) {
              console.log(result) // it says error
            });
        }
      }
      ContractList(log)
    } else {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
```

my console error

```
8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
at Function.t.fromHexString (8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2)
at t._callStaticAsync (8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2)
at t.<anonymous> (8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2)
at 8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2
at Object.next (8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2)
at 8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Module.y (8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2)
at t._ethCall (8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2)
at t.<anonymous> (8d1bc033c0b40cc14af6.js:2)
```

Comment: As soon as you enter the function `function (error, result) {` the value of `this` will change, so the subsequent attempt to access `this.ethAddress` will not be the value you're expecting. Should be easy to confirm with logging. You could solve with an arrow function, or grab the value of `ethAddress` outside the function.

Comment: @skirtle  yeah thanks, it works. I grabbed  `this.ethAddress` outside the function. btw Could you explain why `this` will change inside loop function?

Comment: The value of `this` is scoped to the current function. So every time you enter a new function the value of `this` changes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for details.